# Explain Windows "net view" command switches

Tags: windows

Can someone please explain the difference between these commands.

```
net view
net view /all
net view /domain
net view /all /domain
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From `net help view`:

```
C:\Users\shufler>net help view
The syntax of this command is:

NET VIEW
[\\computername [/CACHE] | [/ALL] | /DOMAIN[:domainname]]

NET VIEW displays a list of resources being shared on a computer. When used
without options, it displays a list of computers in the current domain or
network.

\\computername             Is a computer whose shared resources you want
                           to view.
/DOMAIN:domainname         Specifies the domain for which you want to
                           view the available computers. If domainname is
                           omitted, displays all domains in the local area
                           network.
/CACHE                     Displays the offline client caching settings for
                           the resources on the specified computer
/ALL                             Displays all the shares including the $ shares
```

So let's look at each.

`net view` returns the computers in the current domain or network. This list will only show computers that have file and printer sharing enabled.
`net view /all` shows all shares available, including administrative shares like C$ and admin$
`net view /domain:contoso.com` will list all of the sharing computers in the contoso.com domain
`net view /all /domain` shows all shares (regular and administrative) in the domain

I'm not currently connected to a domain so unfortunately I can't provide you with examples.

Comment: Wow didn't even notice the help command. I kept doing "net view ?" wasn't as detailed.

Comment: @Mike If you tried `net /?` you may have noticed the `help` option.  Follow the rabbit hole from there.

Comment: To be fair, NET is one of maybe a handful of Microsoft console applications that doesn't follow the same input model as other commands. Yes, NET /? shows HELP as an option, but you normally wouldn't expect an additional help system beyond /? for most cmd utilites.